# scp using libcurl fails

Tags: libcurl, libssh2

I am trying to use programmatically libcurl that is built with OpenSSL 1.1.1 and libssh2 to do scp of files. It fails with the error below on the application side. Is there any hint of what could be going wrong?

```
Debug details:   Trying 10.30.10.120...
Debug details: TCP_NODELAY set
Debug details: Connected to 10.30.10.120 (10.30.10.120) port 22 (#1)
Debug details: SSH MD5 fingerprint: 140efbdc7794d4c623f87fe4d95fd69f
Debug details: SSH authentication methods available: publickey,password
Debug details: Using SSH private key file ''
Debug details: SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to extract public key from private key file: Unable to open private key file
Debug details: Authentication failure
Debug details: Closing connection 1
ErrorCode=67, ErrorStr=Login denied
```

On the sshd server side, this is what I see:

```
May 02 01:29:20 test-host isshd[2558229]: debug1: Forked child 2702766.
May 02 01:29:20 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
May 02 01:29:20 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: Connection from 10.30.10.120 port 45954 on 10.30.10.120 port 22 rdomain ""
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh2_1.10.0
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: no match: libssh2_1.10.0
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 106/65534 [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: KEX done [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: userauth-request for user admin service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: error: failed to fetch pwnam using the actual username - trying user xshell\n
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: PAM: initializing for "admin"
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: PAM _pam_load_conf_file: unable to open config for /etc/pam.d/system-auth
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.30.10.120"
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: userauth_send_banner: sent [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for admin: Authentication failure
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: Failed none for admin from 10.30.10.120 port 45954 ssh2
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: Connection closed by authenticating user admin 10.30.10.120 port 45954 [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: sshpam_handle is NULL [preauth]
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: do_cleanup
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: PAM: closing session
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2702766]: debug1: Killing privsep child 2702773
May 02 01:29:21 test-host isshd[2558229]: debug1: main_sigchld_handler: Child exited
```

Comment: _Debug details: SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to open private key file_ looks like a pretty clear hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this turned out to be an issue of using older version of libcurl. Once I upgraded libcurl to recent version 7.68, things worked out fine.